# Google Maps Android Keeping Marker on Map Clear

Tags: android, google-maps

I add markers to my map from an object array which contains their positions. When a marker is clicked, I want it to show an infowindow (which also gets its data from the object array which contains the marker's position).

I have created a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String,Marker> hashMarkers = new HashMap<>();
```

This is the code I use to add the markers. Only the markers within a certain range of the center are added.

```
for (pointNumber= 0; pointNumber<pointArray.length; pointNumber++) {

                    if (distanceToPointFromCenter<range) {
                                 hashMarkers.put(String.valueOf(pointNumber),
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(pointArray[pointNumber].latitude, pointArray[pointNumber].longitude))
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                                        .title("Title: " + pointArray[pointNumber].pointTitle)
                                        .snippet("Snippet: " + pointArray[pointNumber].snippet)));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Out of range");
                    }
                }
```

Since I will have a lot of markers, I clear the map every time the camera is moved using `mMap.clear();` and redraw the markers.

This is my OnMarkerClickListener:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker selectedMarker) {
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (marker.equals(hashMarkers.get("the number of the marker"))) {
                    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(selectedMarker.getPosition())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .title(selectedMarker.getTitle())
                .snippet(selectedMarker.getSnippet()));
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomWindowAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

When I click on a marker, I see the infowindow for a few milliseconds, before it disappears. This happens because the camera is refreshed when the marker is clicked.

I tried recreating the marker and its infowindow inside OnMarkerClick (as shown above), but it does not work.

Is there any way in which I can

1. Prevent only the marker I clicked on from being cleared, or
2. Redraw the marker I clicked and show its infowindow

I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I'm pretty new to programming (and StackOverflow).
Any help given will be appreciated.

Comment: you should remove that particular marker by `marker.remove();`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to remove all the markers _except_ that particular marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the code to redraw the marker after you clear the markers from map.You can save the position of clicked marker with properties in gloabal variables.

**Edit:**

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker selectedMarker) {
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    savedPosition=selectedMarker.getPosition();
                    savedTitle=selectedMarker.getTitle();
                    savedSnippet=selectedMarker.getSnippet();
                  // anything else part of your code..
             }
        });
}
```

after map.clear() add the following:

```
if(savedPosition!=null && savedTitle!=null && savedSnippet!=null){
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(savedPosition)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                    .title(savedTitle)
                    .snippet(savedSnippet));

                    marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Comment: The marker is redrawn after it is cleared. The problem is that when I click a marker to see its infowindow, the camera moves, and because of that, the marker gets removed and redrawn. When this happens, the infowindow gets removed as well.


I can save the position of the marker, but then I would have to draw it again using the saved data. Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: see the code in edit.You can use it to redraw the marker with infowindow.